# ChartJS : How to display two "y axis" scales on a chart

Tags: chart.js

I have a chart that shows various data points.
Some of these data points are high numbers and some are low numbers.

The low numbers (visits) I can scale to a different scale and this new scale can be put on the "X" axis (It's the "Y" axis and then rotated 90degrees). But the problem is:

- The grid remains even when removed
- The

How can I extrapolate the poistion on the graph without adjusting the label data on hover?2 I have search Stackoverflow and ChartJS documentation but can't see how this can be done.

---

I was trying to use the "other" axis (in this case the top horizontal bar of the chart) so that the scale would be relative and raw data editing would not be needed but I can't get that to work and can't find documentation on this. I'm sure it's possible but I can't see how where.

I have found [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44240726/chartjs-using-multiple-y-axes) but this related only to ChartJS V2 .

Current version used is ChartJS 3.2.1

## Original Version:

```js
    var ctx = document.getElementById("historicChart");
    var historicChart = new Chart(ctx, {
            type: "horizontalBar",
            data: {
                labels: [2022,2021,2020,2019,2018,2017,2016],
                datasets: [
                    {
                        type: 'line',
                        label: 'Visits',
                        data: ["1","7","493","163","467","88","48"],
                        backgroundColor: '#FFC900',
                        pointBackgroundColor: '#FFC900',
                        pointRadius: 8,
                        pointStyle: 'circle',
                        showLine: false,
                        order: 1,
                        hoverRadius: 10
                    },
                    {
                        type: 'bar',
                        label: 'Applied',
                        data: ["486","800","704","1084","532","618","543"],
                        backgroundColor: '#436BFF',
                        borderWidth: 0,
                        order: 2,
                        barPercentage: 0.9,
                        stack: 'stack 0',
                    },
                    {
                        type: 'bar',
                        label: 'Accepted',
                        data: ["1","147","290","521","233","306","271"],
                        backgroundColor: '#C40500',
                        borderWidth: 0,
                        barPercentage: 0.9,
                        stack: 'stack 1',
                        order: 4
                    },
                    {
                        type: 'bar',
                        label: 'Declined',
                        data: ["616","4273","3998","3400","922","1225","1184"],
                        /*backgroundColor: '#03570c', /* emerald */
                        backgroundColor: '#006545', /* jade */
                        borderWidth: 0,
                        barPercentage: 0.9,
                        stack: 'stack 0',
                        order: 5
                    },
                    {
                        type: 'bar',
                        label: 'Processing',
                        data: ["6","13","22","1","34","2","1"],
                        backgroundColor: '#65ccD3', /* aqua + blue */
                        borderWidth: 0,
                        barPercentage: 0.9,
                        stack: 'stack 0',
                        order: 3
                    },
                ]
            },
            options: {
                responsive: true,
                interaction: {
                    intersect: false,
                    mode: 'index',
                    axis: 'y'
                },
                indexAxis: 'y',
                scales: {
                    xAxes: [{
                        stacked: true,
                        ticks: {
                            stepSize: 1
                        },
                        beginAtZero: true
                    }],
                    yAxes: [{
                        stacked: true
                    }]
                }
            }
        }
    );
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/3.2.1/chart.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

   <canvas id="historicChart"></canvas>
```

## UPDATE:

I have tried to add a custom secondary axis as per [this example from the CHartJS documentation](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/samples/line/multi-axis.html), but it doesn't quite do as I need; the grid lines remain and the axis scale is on the "wrong" side (two scales on one size (bottom) and zero scales on the other side (top)

```js
var ctx = document.getElementById("historicChart");
    var historicChart = new Chart(ctx, {
            type: "horizontalBar",
            data: {
                labels: [2022,2021,2020,2019,2018,2017,2016],
                datasets: [
                    {
                        type: 'line',
                        label: 'Visits',
                        data: ["1","7","493","163","467","88","48"],
                        backgroundColor: '#FFC900',
                        pointBackgroundColor: '#FFC900',
                        pointRadius: 8,
                        pointStyle: 'circle',
                        showLine: false,
                        order: 1,
                        hoverRadius: 10,
                        xAxisID:'xTwo'
                    },
                    {
                        type: 'bar',
                        label: 'Applied',
                        data: ["486","900","724","1084","532","618","543"],
                        backgroundColor: '#436BFF',
                        borderWidth: 0,
                        order: 2,
                        barPercentage: 0.9,
                        stack: 'stack 0',
                    },
                    {
                        type: 'bar',
                        label: 'Accepted',
                        data: ["1","147","290","511","253","306","271"],
                        backgroundColor: '#C40500',
                        borderWidth: 0,
                        barPercentage: 0.9,
                        stack: 'stack 1',
                        order: 4
                    },
                    {
                        type: 'bar',
                        label: 'Declined',
                        data: ["616","4373","3998","3400","922","1205","1184"],
                        /*backgroundColor: '#03570c', /* emerald */
                        backgroundColor: '#006545', /* jade */
                        borderWidth: 0,
                        barPercentage: 0.9,
                        stack: 'stack 0',
                        order: 5
                    },
                    {
                        type: 'bar',
                        label: 'Processing',
                        data: ["6","23","22","1","4","2","1"],
                        backgroundColor: '#65ccD3', /* aqua + blue */
                        borderWidth: 0,
                        barPercentage: 0.9,
                        stack: 'stack 0',
                        order: 3
                    },
                ]
            },
            options: {
                responsive: true,
                interaction: {
                    intersect: false,
                    mode: 'index',
                    axis: 'y'
                },
                indexAxis: 'y',
                scales: {
                    xAxes: [{
                        stacked: true,
                        ticks: {
                            stepSize: 1
                        },
                        beginAtZero: true
                    }],
                    yAxes: [{
                        stacked: true
                    }],
                    xTwo: [{
                        type: 'linear',
                        display: true,
                        position: 'top',
                        grid: {
                            display: false,
                            drawOnChartArea: false,
                            ticks: {
                                display: false
                            }
                        }
                    }]
                }
            }
        }
    );
```

```html
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/3.2.1/chart.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

       <canvas id="historicChart"></canvas>
```

The issue appears to be with the scale; "xTwo";

```
     xTwo: [{
           type: 'linear',
           display: true,
           position: 'top',
           grid: {
                 display: false,
                 drawOnChartArea: false,
                 ticks: {
                 /* trying to even just hide the ticks here fails */
                         display: false,
                 }
           }
     }]
```

How can I fix this to hide the grid lines and put the scale on the correct side of the graph?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a custom label callback for this in the tooltip config, also your scale config was wrong. It was in V2 style. For all changes please read the [migration guide](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/3.7.1/getting-started/v3-migration.html)

```js
var ctx = document.getElementById("historicChart");
var historicChart = new Chart(ctx, {
  type: "horizontalBar",
  data: {
    labels: [2022, 2021, 2020, 2019, 2018, 2017, 2016],
    datasets: [{
        type: 'line',
        label: 'Visits',
        data: ["5", "35", "2465", "815", "2335", "440", "240"],
        backgroundColor: '#FFC900',
        pointBackgroundColor: '#FFC900',
        pointRadius: 8,
        pointStyle: 'circle',
        showLine: false,
        order: 1,
        hoverRadius: 10
      },
      {
        type: 'bar',
        label: 'Applied',
        data: ["486", "800", "704", "1084", "532", "618", "543"],
        backgroundColor: '#436BFF',
        borderWidth: 0,
        order: 2,
        barPercentage: 0.9,
        stack: 'stack 0',
      },
      {
        type: 'bar',
        label: 'Accepted',
        data: ["1", "147", "290", "521", "233", "306", "271"],
        backgroundColor: '#C40500',
        borderWidth: 0,
        barPercentage: 0.9,
        stack: 'stack 1',
        order: 4
      },
      {
        type: 'bar',
        label: 'Declined',
        data: ["616", "4273", "3998", "3400", "922", "1225", "1184"],
        /*backgroundColor: '#03570c', /* emerald */
        backgroundColor: '#006545',
        /* jade */
        borderWidth: 0,
        barPercentage: 0.9,
        stack: 'stack 0',
        order: 5
      },
      {
        type: 'bar',
        label: 'Processing',
        data: ["6", "13", "22", "1", "34", "2", "1"],
        backgroundColor: '#65ccD3',
        /* aqua + blue */
        borderWidth: 0,
        barPercentage: 0.9,
        stack: 'stack 0',
        order: 3
      },
    ]
  },
  options: {
    responsive: true,
    interaction: {
      intersect: false,
      mode: 'index',
      axis: 'y'
    },
    indexAxis: 'y',
    plugins: {
      tooltip: {
        callbacks: {
          label: (ttItem) => {
            const label = ttItem.dataset.label;
            const val = Number(ttItem.raw);

            let res = `${label}: ${label === 'Visits' ? val / 5 : val}`;
            return res
          }
        }
      }
    },
    scales: {
      x: {
        stacked: true,
        ticks: {
          stepSize: 1
        },
        beginAtZero: true
      },
      y: {
        stacked: true
      }
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/3.2.1/chart.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<canvas id="historicChart"></canvas>
```

**UPDATE:**
You tried adding a second scale, in chart.js V3 all scales are their own objects and not arrays anymore, for all changes see migration guide linked above. Changing the scales to objects fixes your issue in your updated approach without needing to multiply values :

```js
var ctx = document.getElementById("historicChart");
var historicChart = new Chart(ctx, {
  type: "horizontalBar",
  data: {
    labels: [2022, 2021, 2020, 2019, 2018, 2017, 2016],
    datasets: [{
        type: 'line',
        label: 'Visits',
        data: ["1", "7", "493", "163", "467", "88", "48"],
        backgroundColor: '#FFC900',
        pointBackgroundColor: '#FFC900',
        pointRadius: 8,
        pointStyle: 'circle',
        showLine: false,
        order: 1,
        hoverRadius: 10,
        xAxisID: 'xTwo'
      },
      {
        type: 'bar',
        label: 'Applied',
        data: ["486", "900", "724", "1084", "532", "618", "543"],
        backgroundColor: '#436BFF',
        borderWidth: 0,
        order: 2,
        barPercentage: 0.9,
        stack: 'stack 0',
      },
      {
        type: 'bar',
        label: 'Accepted',
        data: ["1", "147", "290", "511", "253", "306", "271"],
        backgroundColor: '#C40500',
        borderWidth: 0,
        barPercentage: 0.9,
        stack: 'stack 1',
        order: 4
      },
      {
        type: 'bar',
        label: 'Declined',
        data: ["616", "4373", "3998", "3400", "922", "1205", "1184"],
        /*backgroundColor: '#03570c', /* emerald */
        backgroundColor: '#006545',
        /* jade */
        borderWidth: 0,
        barPercentage: 0.9,
        stack: 'stack 0',
        order: 5
      },
      {
        type: 'bar',
        label: 'Processing',
        data: ["6", "23", "22", "1", "4", "2", "1"],
        backgroundColor: '#65ccD3',
        /* aqua + blue */
        borderWidth: 0,
        barPercentage: 0.9,
        stack: 'stack 0',
        order: 3
      },
    ]
  },
  options: {
    responsive: true,
    interaction: {
      intersect: false,
      mode: 'index',
      axis: 'y'
    },
    indexAxis: 'y',
    scales: {
      x: {
        stacked: true,
        ticks: {
          stepSize: 1000
        },
        beginAtZero: true
      },
      y: {
        stacked: true
      },
      xTwo: {
        type: 'linear',
        display: true,
        position: 'top',
        grid: {
          display: false,
          ticks: {
            display: false
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/3.2.1/chart.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<canvas id="historicChart"></canvas>
```

Comment: Yes but scale config is even more wrong now, every scale is its own object and not array, changing that will make it so the config applies like I did in my answer

Comment: Oh that's fantastic, fixing the scale issue corrects my problems and removes the need to multiply the data values.

Comment: If you could clarify and highlight this in your answer I can give you the tick, thank you!

Comment: Change stepSize from 1 to 1000 in the ticks from the x axis, see updated sample with 2 x axes

Comment: Oh farts, I'm a fkn clown; I saw x-axis stepsize was 1 and thought that was the "date", but of course, if I set the x-axis stepsize to what I need (250) that works perfectly. Thanks. Because the graph is rotated I guess. Anyway, all great. thanks again `:-)`